# Why Selenium is not using JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm a noob who has been for some time learning Javascript with the only purpose of using it to write Selenium automations (ultimately the purpose is to lear QA automation).

The problem is that I'm totally confused when it comes to the language. All I see in Selenium documentation and scritp examples are functions like "driver.FindElement", "sendKeys", "getTitle", etc.

As far as I've learnt, (pure) Javascript doesn't use these functions but rather "document.getElementById", "document.title", etc.

Can you please help me to identify what language is Selenium using, when it says "sendKeys"? Why in all documentation I find about Selenium+Javascript I just see "getTitle" instead of "document.title"? WHat I've learnt about pure JS is not applicable for this tool?

I know this is probably one of the most stupid questions you have seen, but I can't continue learning until I understand what is happening here. Thanks!

Comment: [Selenium + JavaScript](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/getting-started/javascript/) has its own syntax while common JavaScript methods and properties like `document.title` still can be used via JavaScriptExecutor

Comment: I see, thanks! Which one of both options would you choose to write automation scripts? I really don't know what is the most commonly used in the QA automation position, and therefore which one will increase the chances to be hired.

Comment: No. JavaScriptExecutor is not a separate tool, but a method of Selenium which allows to execute pure JavaScript. I'm not sure about syntax, but it's usage will look pretty much like `var title = driver.executeScript('return document.title;')`

Answer (score 1):

The `document.getElementById` and `document.title` is the JavaScript HTML DOM API. You can use it to write automation script in JavaScript.

But you must run such automation script in browser side, either in browser's DevTool's console, or you make the HTML page includes your automation script via `<script src='<your automation script><script>'` into the page source code.

Thinking about how you can inject your automation script into a web page of a website not owned by you. And even if you test your owned website, your automation script will be loaded and executed as long as the page is loading. It's difficulty for you to manage the running process, package your website to include automation script on your site page, etc. And use JavaScript to write automation script only.

Thus using this way to automate web page is not a wise solution.

Selenium is an web automation tool relying on Webdriver.  Webdriver acts as a proxy between Selenium API and real browser. Each browser vendor will develop and maintain self webdriver (Webdriver is an executable binary), but all browser vendors must follow the Webdriver W3C specification to implement self wedriver, so that when your script calls same Selenium API on same page in different browser, you can get same result.

Like `driver.findElement` and `driver.sendKeys` are selenium APIs which you use to compose your automation script.  And selenium supplies different language APIs, like python, javascript, Java, ruby, c#, VBA, perl, php.  You can choose your preferred script language.  The method name, usage are different on different language API.

Webdriver binary can only accept http requests, it can't execute method/function of Selenium API.  You can think when webdriver binary started, an http server runs inside it to accept the http request sent from your automation script.

Actually, each language's selenium APIs had implemented to translate all APIs' method to a http request, then send the request to the running webdriver binary, then webdriver binary will translate the http request to actions on browser.

All implementations of WebDriver binary that communicates with the browser use a common wire protocol. This wire protocol defines a RESTful web service using JSON over HTTP, named `The WebDriver JSON Wire Protocol`, More detail at [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).